# XML to Word: XSL to recognize bold in text

Tags: xslt

I have an XML:

```
<RecipeDetail>
  <FMIngredientsLine>Vegetables, Soy Sauce [Soy Sauce Powder [&lt;b&gt;Soya&lt;/b&gt; Beans, Salt]]</FMIngredientsLine>
</RecipeDetail>
```

I am using an XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PackCopy/Recipe/RecipeDetail">
  <xsl:value-of select="FMIngredientsLine"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

When I open word it displays as:

> Vegetables, Soy Sauce [Soy Sauce Powder [<b>Soya</b> Beans, Salt]]

I want it to be displayed as

> Vegetables, Soy Sauce [Soy Sauce Powder [**Soya** Beans, Salt]]

Soya needs to be in bold.

Comment: Does using `<xsl:value-of select="FMIngredientsLine" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` fix the problem? If not, which document format exactly are you trying to create for Word?

Comment: I have put my suggestion in an answer so that you can accept it and your question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are transforming to a format where Word recognizes the HTML `b` element you can use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` on the `xsl:value-of`, i.e. `<xsl:value-of select="FMIngredientsLine" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`.